# Change Radius of arc

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, github

[image]I am using this Github Library https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress.

But i am not getting how to increse size of arc or chane its circumference means its starting and ending point .

I am unable to it ,please help in it .

Here is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#4a4a4a" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <!-- Player Header -->
    <!-- Progress Bar/Seek bar -->
    <com.androidhive.musicplayer.equalizer.ArcProgress
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
          android:background="#214193"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        custom:arc_progress="55"
        custom:arc_bottom_text="MEMORY"/>     


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is ArcProgress.java

```
package com.androidhive.musicplayer.equalizer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import com.androidhive.musicplayer.R;

/**
 * Created by bruce on 11/6/14.
 */
public class ArcProgress extends View {
    private Paint paint;
    protected Paint textPaint;

    private RectF rectF = new RectF();

    private float strokeWidth;
    private float suffixTextSize;
    private float bottomTextSize;
    private String bottomText;
    private float textSize;
    private int textColor;
    private int progress = 0;
    private int max;
    private int finishedStrokeColor;
    private int unfinishedStrokeColor;
    private float arcAngle;
    private String suffixText = "%";
    private float suffixTextPadding;

    private float arcBottomHeight;

    private final int default_finished_color = Color.WHITE;
    private final int default_unfinished_color = Color.rgb(72, 106, 176);
    private final int default_text_color = Color.rgb(66, 145, 241);
    private final float default_suffix_text_size;
    private final float default_suffix_padding;
    private final float default_bottom_text_size;
    private final float default_stroke_width;
    private final String default_suffix_text;
    private final int default_max = 100;
    private final float default_arc_angle = 360 * 0.8f;
    private float default_text_size;
    private final int min_size;

    private static final String INSTANCE_STATE = "saved_instance";
    private static final String INSTANCE_STROKE_WIDTH = "stroke_width";
    private static final String INSTANCE_SUFFIX_TEXT_SIZE = "suffix_text_size";
    private static final String INSTANCE_SUFFIX_TEXT_PADDING = "suffix_text_padding";
    private static final String INSTANCE_BOTTOM_TEXT_SIZE = "bottom_text_size";
    private static final String INSTANCE_BOTTOM_TEXT = "bottom_text";
    private static final String INSTANCE_TEXT_SIZE = "text_size";
    private static final String INSTANCE_TEXT_COLOR = "text_color";
    private static final String INSTANCE_PROGRESS = "progress";
    private static final String INSTANCE_MAX = "max";
    private static final String INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_COLOR = "finished_stroke_color";
    private static final String INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_COLOR = "unfinished_stroke_color";
    private static final String INSTANCE_ARC_ANGLE = "arc_angle";
    private static final String INSTANCE_SUFFIX = "suffix";

    public ArcProgress(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ArcProgress(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ArcProgress(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        default_text_size = Utils.sp2px(getResources(), 18);
        min_size = (int) Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 100);
        default_text_size = Utils.sp2px(getResources(), 40);
        default_suffix_text_size = Utils.sp2px(getResources(), 15);
        default_suffix_padding = Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 4);
        default_suffix_text = "%";
        default_bottom_text_size = Utils.sp2px(getResources(), 10);
        default_stroke_width = Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 4);

        TypedArray attributes = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ArcProgress, defStyleAttr, 0);
        initByAttributes(attributes);
        attributes.recycle();

        initPainters();
    }

    protected void initByAttributes(TypedArray attributes) {
        finishedStrokeColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_finished_color, default_finished_color);
        unfinishedStrokeColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_unfinished_color, default_unfinished_color);
        textColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_text_color, default_text_color);
        textSize = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_text_size, default_text_size);
        arcAngle = attributes.getFloat(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_angle, default_arc_angle);
        setMax(attributes.getInt(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_max, default_max));
        setProgress(attributes.getInt(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_progress, 0));
        strokeWidth = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_stroke_width, default_stroke_width);
        suffixTextSize = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_suffix_text_size, default_suffix_text_size);
        suffixText = TextUtils.isEmpty(attributes.getString(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_suffix_text)) ? default_suffix_text : attributes.getString(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_suffix_text);
        suffixTextPadding = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_suffix_text_padding, default_suffix_padding);
        bottomTextSize = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_bottom_text_size, default_bottom_text_size);
        bottomText = attributes.getString(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_bottom_text);
    }

    protected void initPainters() {
        textPaint = new TextPaint();
        textPaint.setColor(textColor);
        textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(default_unfinished_color);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        initPainters();
        super.invalidate();
    }

    public float getStrokeWidth() {
        return strokeWidth;
    }

    public void setStrokeWidth(float strokeWidth) {
        this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public float getSuffixTextSize() {
        return suffixTextSize;
    }

    public void setSuffixTextSize(float suffixTextSize) {
        this.suffixTextSize = suffixTextSize;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public String getBottomText() {
        return bottomText;
    }

    public void setBottomText(String bottomText) {
        this.bottomText = bottomText;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
        if (this.progress > getMax()) {
            this.progress %= getMax();
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        if (max > 0) {
            this.max = max;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public float getBottomTextSize() {
        return bottomTextSize;
    }

    public void setBottomTextSize(float bottomTextSize) {
        this.bottomTextSize = bottomTextSize;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public float getTextSize() {
        return textSize;
    }

    public void setTextSize(float textSize) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getTextColor() {
        return textColor;
    }

    public void setTextColor(int textColor) {
        this.textColor = textColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getFinishedStrokeColor() {
        return finishedStrokeColor;
    }

    public void setFinishedStrokeColor(int finishedStrokeColor) {
        this.finishedStrokeColor = finishedStrokeColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getUnfinishedStrokeColor() {
        return unfinishedStrokeColor;
    }

    public void setUnfinishedStrokeColor(int unfinishedStrokeColor) {
        this.unfinishedStrokeColor = unfinishedStrokeColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public float getArcAngle() {
        return arcAngle;
    }

    public void setArcAngle(float arcAngle) {
        this.arcAngle = arcAngle;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public String getSuffixText() {
        return suffixText;
    }

    public void setSuffixText(String suffixText) {
        this.suffixText = suffixText;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public float getSuffixTextPadding() {
        return suffixTextPadding;
    }

    public void setSuffixTextPadding(float suffixTextPadding) {
        this.suffixTextPadding = suffixTextPadding;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getSuggestedMinimumHeight() {
        return min_size;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getSuggestedMinimumWidth() {
        return min_size;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        rectF.set(strokeWidth / 2f, strokeWidth / 2f, width - strokeWidth / 2f, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) - strokeWidth / 2f);
        float radius = width / 2f;
        float angle = (360 - arcAngle) / 2f;
        arcBottomHeight = radius * (float) (1 - Math.cos(angle / 180 * Math.PI));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        float startAngle = 270 - arcAngle / 2f;
        float finishedSweepAngle = progress / (float) getMax() * arcAngle;
        float finishedStartAngle = startAngle;
        paint.setColor(unfinishedStrokeColor);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, startAngle, arcAngle, false, paint);
        paint.setColor(finishedStrokeColor);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, finishedStartAngle, finishedSweepAngle, false, paint);

        String text = String.valueOf(getProgress());
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            textPaint.setColor(textColor);
            textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
            float textHeight = textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent();
            float textBaseline = (getHeight() - textHeight) / 2.0f;
            canvas.drawText(text, (getWidth() - textPaint.measureText(text)) / 2.0f, textBaseline, textPaint);
            textPaint.setTextSize(suffixTextSize);
            float suffixHeight = textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent();
            canvas.drawText(suffixText, getWidth() / 2.0f  + textPaint.measureText(text) + suffixTextPadding, textBaseline + textHeight - suffixHeight, textPaint);
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getBottomText())) {
            textPaint.setTextSize(bottomTextSize);
            float bottomTextBaseline = getHeight() - arcBottomHeight - (textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent()) / 2;
            canvas.drawText(getBottomText(), (getWidth() - textPaint.measureText(getBottomText())) / 2.0f, bottomTextBaseline, textPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(INSTANCE_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_STROKE_WIDTH, getStrokeWidth());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_SUFFIX_TEXT_SIZE, getSuffixTextSize());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_SUFFIX_TEXT_PADDING, getSuffixTextPadding());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_BOTTOM_TEXT_SIZE, getBottomTextSize());
        bundle.putString(INSTANCE_BOTTOM_TEXT, getBottomText());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_TEXT_SIZE, getTextSize());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_TEXT_COLOR, getTextColor());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_PROGRESS, getProgress());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_MAX, getMax());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_COLOR, getFinishedStrokeColor());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_COLOR, getUnfinishedStrokeColor());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_ARC_ANGLE, getArcAngle());
        bundle.putString(INSTANCE_SUFFIX, getSuffixText());
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if(state instanceof Bundle) {
            final Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
            strokeWidth = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_STROKE_WIDTH);
            suffixTextSize = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_SUFFIX_TEXT_SIZE);
            suffixTextPadding = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_SUFFIX_TEXT_PADDING);
            bottomTextSize = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_BOTTOM_TEXT_SIZE);
            bottomText = bundle.getString(INSTANCE_BOTTOM_TEXT);
            textSize = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_TEXT_SIZE);
            textColor = bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_TEXT_COLOR);
            setMax(bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_MAX));
            setProgress(bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_PROGRESS));
            finishedStrokeColor = bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_COLOR);
            unfinishedStrokeColor = bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_COLOR);
            suffixText = bundle.getString(INSTANCE_SUFFIX);
            initPainters();
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(INSTANCE_STATE));
            return;
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }
}
```

I want to increase radius of arc and increase circumference of it .
Any hep wil be appreciated .
Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Add `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to the root `RelativeLayout` in your layout XML.

Comment: increase the value of  `android:layout_width="100dp"`

Comment: For starting point ?.......i mean for circumference

Comment: Be careful when you completely change a question. Just make sure nobody's answered it, and you update the tags appropriately. You're generally good this time, but I don't think [github] is relevant here.

Comment: what you exactly want to change? Did increasing the size work for you?

Comment: Yeah thanks for it......i want to change look of arc also....how can i do that ...Arcprogresss class is taking inbuilt drawable i think .........please suggest me how to change look of arc that it shows in layout @Blackbelt

Comment: you can change its color. Is it that you want to change ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to increase radius of arc and increase circumference of it

Accordingly to the code you posted, the size is decide during `onMeasure`

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    rectF.set(strokeWidth / 2f, strokeWidth / 2f, width - strokeWidth / 2f, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) - strokeWidth / 2f);
    float radius = width / 2f;
    float angle = (360 - arcAngle) / 2f;
    arcBottomHeight = radius * (float) (1 - Math.cos(angle / 180 * Math.PI));
}
```

So, in order to increase the radius, you have to increase width and height your provide in the layout. If you want to change the arc's color you can provide statically, in the xml

`arc_finished_color` and `arc_unfinished_color`

E.g.

```
<com.androidhive.musicplayer.equalizer.ArcProgress
    android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
    android:background="#214193"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:arc_progress="55" 
    custom:arc_bottom_text="MEMORY"
    custom:arc_finished_color="@color/finished_color" 
    custom:arc_unfinished_color="@color/unfinished_color"/>
```

Comment: Check the pic....i want ring in that way.like in dots .is it possible ? @Blackbelt

Comment: you can check [here](https://android-arsenal.com/) if you can find something that suits your needs, or write one on your own

Comment: Can u suggest some changes in it i shud make to make ring like as in pic?  @Blackbelt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759871/how-to-make-a-custom-rotating-knob-with-multimeter......i stated bounty here....please help if u can..i seriously need this type of view.